# Why is simple Stack code from Flutter website is giving Error?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(StackApp());
}
```

**Simple Class Stack I am trying to use the stack to overlay rectangles one above the other**

```
 class StackApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 90,
              height: 90,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 80,
              height: 80,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

**I am getting this error message**
I/flutter ( 8912): (elided 10 frames from class _AssertionError, package dart:async, and package dart:async-patch)

I/flutter ( 8912):
I/flutter ( 8912): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: 
RenderStack#322e9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:

I/flutter ( 8912):   creator: Stack ← StackApp ← [root]

I/flutter ( 8912):   parentData:

I/flutter ( 8912):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=866.3)

I/flutter ( 8912):   size: MISSING

I/flutter ( 8912):   alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart

I/flutter ( 8912):   textDirection: null

I/flutter ( 8912):   fit: loose

I/flutter ( 8912):   overflow: clip

I/flutter ( 8912): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):

I/flutter ( 8912):     child 1: RenderConstrainedBox#49f71 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

I/flutter ( 8912):       child: RenderDecoratedBox#2c55a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

I/flutter ( 8912):     child 2: RenderConstrainedBox#c71ea NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

I/flutter ( 8912):       child: RenderDecoratedBox#4ad6c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

I/flutter ( 8912):     child 3: RenderConstrainedBox#5304a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

I/flutter ( 8912):       child: RenderDecoratedBox#9516e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

I/flutter ( 8912): 
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your app in a `MaterialApp`, `CupertinoApp` or `WidgetsApp`. This is almost mandatory. But if you don't want to use one of these for some reason, then set `alignment` in your Stack like `alignment: Alignment.topLeft`  to fix this.